# How to populate a select dropdown with a list of JSON values using JS fetch()?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In the snippet below, I'm trying to populate a list of states in a select dropdown using a fetch request. I'm able to console the list of states from a local json file.

I am able to console the list of states properly, but the select menu is not populating at all? I don't see any errors and I'm wondering where I went wrong?

**Is there something wrong with my fetch request syntactically?**

```js
const states = document.getElementById('states');
states.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>';

fetch('https://jarednewnam.com/test/states.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status) {
      res.data.forEach(state => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = state.abbr;
        let node = document.createTextNode(state.state)
        option.appendChild(node);
        states.appendChild(option);
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<select name="states" id="states"></select>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code is that a) there is no `innerContent` property on HTML elements, you're probably thinking of `textContent`, and b) you're not attaching your `option` elements that you create, to the select element (`states`). Feel free to delete your question when you're done :)

Comment: I've updated my OP to include some live json data. Can you explain what you meant in **b)** better?

Comment: You create a bunch of `<option>`. But where in your code are you actually appending then to the `<select>`? Do you expect that to happen magically?

Comment: Magic, no! I suppose that's where I'm lost.

Comment: Why not use the Option constructor, and the select dom element .add function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*
let statesSelect = document.getElementById('states');
let newDefault = new Option('Select State', null, true, true)
newDefault.disabled = true
statesSelect.add(newDefault)

fetch("https://jarednewnam.com/test/states.json")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const { states } = data;
        states.forEach((state) => {
            let option = new Option(state.name, state.abbreviation);
            statesSelect.add(option);
        });
    });
*/      
let todos = document.getElementById('placeholder');
let newDefault1 = new Option('Select todo', null, true, true)
newDefault1.disabled = true
todos.add(newDefault1)

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
      data.forEach(todo => {
        let option = new Option(todo.title, todo.id)
        console.log(option)
        todos.add(option)
      });
  });
```

```html
<!--<select name="states" id="states"></select> <p>your select</p>-->
<select name="placeholder" id="placeholder"></select>
```

This should work and is in my opinion cleaner than doing it with DOM manipulation functions.

For later people reading it, the commented out part is the specific answer to his question, with his data but that data doesn't exist anymore so I commented it out.

Comment: But the list of states are not populating. Why? The JSON file is [https://jarednewnam.com/test/states.json](https://jarednewnam.com/test/states.json).

Comment: CORS blocking it, if it's just not working on stackOverflow

Comment: Not working locally either. And I'm not using an external URL.

Comment: Got it working it was cause the fetch was wrong like the syntax also in your original one, u use then so you don't need to check for status you can't even you get just the response data there.

Comment: I've copied your solution word-for-word and replaced it with my local json file (`/data/DATA_States.json`), but the content isn't loading.

Comment: Does the local file have the exact same file structure as the one we use in these solutions like the one you uploaded?

Comment: Yes. You can see the [file here](https://jarednewnam.com/test/states.json). I'm using it locally, but this is the structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248027/discussion-between-td3v-and-millhorn).

Comment: it probably would be nice to include the raw json also so that when people look at this later on and the file is no longer available via the url given that its still something they can replicate

Answer (score 0):

You should append options to select element, missing code `states.appendChild(option);`

```js
const states = document.getElementById('states');
states.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>';

fetch('https://jarednewnam.com/test/states.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    if (res.status) {
      res.data.forEach(state => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = state.abbr;
        option.innerHTML = state.state;
        states.appendChild(option);
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<select name="states" id="states"></select>
```

Comment: If that's what I'm missing, why isn't the list of states populating?

Comment: check logs there is a CORS issue

Comment: yo FYI: this can't work res.data is not valid in the second then you just get the response data and nothing more only response body content.
And since we are promise based there is no need to check for the requst state.

Comment: Can you assist me in getting it to work? I'm not sure where to go.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something wrong with my fetch request syntactically?

Nothing wrong with your fetch.

What you're missing is attaching the nodes you're creating inside the forEach loop.
Here's an example, I'm using typicode to get a list of something since the api you used doesn't pass browser cors preflight for SO, but I think you should get the point:

```js
const states = document.getElementById('states');
states.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>';

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
   
      res.forEach(state => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = state.id;
        option.innerHTML = state.title;
        states.append(option)
      });

  });
```

```html
<select name="states" id="states"></select>
```

Comment: You tell him no there is nothing wrong, but in your answer you just silently alter the syntax of the second then from the fetch yes there is somehting wrong, he is trying to access a property, that isn't there at this point.